# How to install lightscribe for CD burning?

Tags: installation, burning

If I want to install lightscribe for CD burning, how do I install it safely?

How to use simply use it?

1. How to install?
2. How to use it? (simple, quick way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**32-Bit Installation**

If you have a 32-bit system, you should be good to go!  Just install the debs, like so:

```
sudo dpkg -i lightscribe*.deb
sudo dpkg -i 4l*.deb
```

Now I haven’t tested this because I do not have a 32-bit system so if you have trouble, let us know in the comments!  I can always cook up a VM to test this in properly.

**64-Bit Installation**

If you are using a 64-bit operating system, which I would wager to guess that that is true, you will have to force the software onto your system.  This is never recommended, but i can’t imagine that the impact of the software is significant enough to cause any damage to your install.  The Ubuntu help page however, gives the following warning;

So, that said, here are the commands!

```
sudo dpkg --install --force architecture lightscribe*.deb
sudo dpkg --install --force-architecture 4l*.deb
```

Now, let’s run it.

If you want to create a disc with an image covering the surface:

```
sudo 4L-gui
```

If all you need to do it print a little text on a disc:

```
/opt/lightscribeApplications/SimpleLabeler/SimpleLabeler
```

Answer (score 4):

The following method was succesfully tested on 15.04 64bit:

1. Install the following dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdebi libsm6:i386
   ```
2. Download the Lightscribe deb packages from the Pawtec website:

   ```
   wget http://www.pawtec.com/lightscribe_files/Linux/LSS/lightscribe-1.18.27.10-linux-2.6-intel.deb
   wget http://www.pawtec.com/lightscribe_files/Linux/LSL/lightscribeApplications-1.18.15.1-linux-2.6-intel.deb
   ```
3. Download the multi-arch version of LaCie 4L Labeler utility created by [Davide Depau](https://launchpad.net/~davideddu).

   ```
   wget http://download.tuxfamily.org/davidedduos/misc/4l_1.0-1_i386.deb
   ```
4. Install the Lightscribe deb packages:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i lightscribe*.deb
   ```
5. Install the LaCie 4L Labeler utility and its dependencies with:

   ```
   sudo gdebi 4l_1.0-1_i386.deb
   ```

Now to create labels run:

```
/opt/lightscribeApplications/SimpleLabeler/SimpleLabeler
```

To burn your disc type:

```
4L-gui
```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LightScribe

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. I just want to add that I installed the `.deb` packages from the Software Center and not from the command line as you suggested. This installs the program files with the current user set as owner. When I tried to burn I'd get an error `Printing requires root privileges`, even if I started the labeler with sudo. The solution was to change the owner and group of the labeler to root: `chown -R root:root /usr/share/4L` and `chown root:root /usr/bin/4L*`. Then I did `gksudo 4L-gui` to run the labeler.

Comment: Heey! this worked for me too on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS! \o/

Comment: What would this method look like in 2022? (FYI: the URLs in step 2 are broken.)